# Change header image on a particular page

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, headers, header-image

In my WP Project i have used "Multiple Domain Mapping" Plugin & "Woocommerce" Plugin. In my child theme i'm mapping the url of the pages which has a top level product category "furniture" with another domain "xyz.com" using Multiple domain mapping plugin.

[image: Header on main pages]

Now i need to show different image as the logo instead of "Shopkeeper" on the header section in all the pages which starts with "xyz.com" domain or its top level product category is "furniture". Can any one knows how can i attain this???

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a different archive template for '**furniture**' category where you will use a custom header.

But if you want to show **furniture** template in both domains with different logo in that case you need to see what filter is provided by *Multiple Domain Mapping* to distinguish between the domains and load the header accordingly.